# How data is stored in Result Set's Object

Tags: servlets

When we use an object of the class ResultSet to store the data that is retrieved from the sql query, how it is store in the object.
If we want to get third column of the first row we can do it some what like this 
ResultSet rs=ps.ExecuteQuery();
if(rs.next())
{
                     out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
But what should we do if we want to see the data in the third column of the second row.

Comment: ``ResultSet#next()``.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call rs.next() it goes to the next row (except the first time, when it goes to the first row).

So when you expect only one row, you can use

```
if(rs.next())
```

But when you expect multiple rows use

```
while(rs.next())
```

Also, your code does not take "the third column of the second row" but rather the third column of the first row.  The first time you call rs.next() it actually goes to the First row.  If you never called rs.next() but try to grab the data from a field, that will give you an error because you haven't moved to any row yet.

Comment: Thanks.for the answer